# opendir( ) sigsegv in GNU C library

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm using Eclipse on Linux on an x86-64 arch.  I'm getting a seg fault at the call to opendir() when passing it a null pointer.

```
char* directory = NULL;

/*
 * ...
 * Get directory from the command line.  If not given, directory will be NULL.
 * ...
 */

DIR* dir = opendir( directory ); // Seg fault here with null pointer.  Instruction: cmpb $0x0,(%rdi)
```

I could put a simple guard line before the call to opendir() to check for a null pointer.  However, I find it strange that the first line of the opendir() method wouldn't be something like:

```
if( dir == NULL )
    return NULL;
```

Am I just being pedantic here, or am I missing something?

As an aside, I'm curious why the fault occurs at the cmpb opcode?  Also, Eclipse shows nothing about the seg fault in the signals pane.

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Comment: You're missing that hiding bugs like the bug in your code by silently taking some default action when encountering a null pointer is a bad practice that perpetuates bad code. `opendir` requires a pointer to a string; this is how it is documented. `NULL` is not a pointer to a string. Therefore, undefined behavior results. Fix your code. Move along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a design decision - many functions in the standard library and POSIX behave the way you describe.  Error checking is the caller's responsibility.  Try calling `strlen()` with a null pointer - it will likely behave the same way.

In your case, the failing instruction seems to make sense.  RDI is probably the null pointer, and attempting to dereference that null pointer causes the segmentation fault.  The `cmpb` instruction in question appears to be part of a loop detecting for the null terminator of the passed-in string.

Comment: Thanks Carl.  Any idea why Eclipse doesn't give any indication of sigsegv in the signals pane?

Comment: @Andrew, sorry - I've never used Eclipse.